# Yii cannot insert string with space into postgreSQL database table

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, pdo

I am using PDO to insert values into postgreSQL database. I am trying to insert the path of a file into the table. The problem is that when the file name contains space then it is inserting the partial file name upto the space.
Below is the code.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from sp_email_attachment_insert(:message_id,:attachment_url);");
$command->bindParam(":message_id",$this->message_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":attachment_url",$this->attachment_url,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result=$command->queryAll();
```

Below is the postgreSQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_email_attachment_insert(_message_id integer, _attachment character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

INSERT INTO message_attachment(message_id,attachment) VALUES(_message_id,_attachment);

exception when others then 
    raise exception '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION sp_email_attachment_insert(integer, character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the value "$this->attachment_url" to make sure it's correct? And could you show us the function sp_email_attachment_insert() to see what is happening?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, you could use serialize  (on insert/update) and unserialize (on select), to avoid the breaking of the string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @FrankHeikens  Value in "$this->attachment_url" is correct. I have updated the question.

Comment: and what type is used for column attachment? If it's (for example) a VARCHAR(10), any input longer than 10 characters will be truncated. (standard SQL behavior, by the spec). Does the function work correct when you use it manually? (using pgAdmin or another client)

Comment: @FrankHeikens  Sorry. Problem was not with PDO. It is in the jquery which is used to show the attachment.